# Configure BizTalk - Change database names

Tags: rename, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I want to configure 2 separate BizTalk environments on the same sql instance.

Is it possible to change the default database names at the time of configuring BizTalk 2020 for one environment?
Will it work if I change the names like below and hit configure.

1. BizTalkMsgBoxDb20
2. BizTalkMgmtDb20
3. BizTalkDTADb20 likewise...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create a new instance on the same DB server.  Yes, I believe it is possible to change the database names when configuring it and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf, I also think it should be possible. I was hoping if somebody could share similar experience and give an actual finding if there wasn't any issue.

Comment: I have seen environments where they renamed the DBs, but I do vaguely recall it did have some issues, but I can't recall of hand what those were.

Comment: I believe it should work.  I have worked places where they had non-standard names.